# Whether to choose Joomla or not for a job portal

Tags: joomla

I am currently looking to get my job portal (www.jobsinajiffy.com) revamped by an outsourced contract. In its new version, it would use LinkedIn and Twitter APIs and would also have microsites for employers with videos and blogposts. I have to **decide between Joomla and hand-coding/PHP** for the portal development, since competing contractors have suggested these two approaches.

There are several opinions out there regarding what to choose but none of them address a site like this. I am reaching out to you in the hope that you (or somebody you know) can help me make a choice between Joomla and hand-coding with respect to the following parameters:
a)Page load speeds

b)Design customization

c)Stability

d)Ability to handle high traffic

e)Any other points to keep in mind

Comment: Questions that are this open ended tend to get voted down and closed. You need to research your options and make a decision.  Myself, and probably others, would be glad to help you with any Joomla related info you might need in order to make your decision - over on the Joomla forums.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Dean. I have tried to find answers to my specific queries by searching through forums but have not found them. I can definitely read detailed documentation about Joomla and about hand-coding and assimilate that information to form an informed opinion (and believe me, T know that would be the best way to go). Unfortunately, I am in a position where I need to find answers quickly and hence rely on experts to help out. I was hoping to get some answers on StackOverflow, but I guess I will have to continue looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - if I were going the Joomla route for this project I would consider one of the following paths:

a) SOBI Pro - allows you to create multiple directories within one component. Create a directory of positions that people can browse, and a separate directory of potential employees that an agency (or the employers - depending upon how you want it) can search, sort, filter the applicants

b) use an off the shelf employment component - there are a number, but to be honest all the ones I've tried have had limitations in their flexibility.  If you find one that is close to what you want you could have it modified.

JomSocial or Community builder could facilitate the subsites areas perhaps - depending upon what you need. Alternatively there are plenty of blogging add-ons available. In fact K2 or one of the other CCK extensions (Zoo, for example) might be capable of being both blog and job directory.  Insertion of video is trivial, whether hosted locally, or remotely Amazon S3, YouTube, etc.

The Joomla Extensions Directory JED http://extensions.joomla.org/ is your friend. Start by browsing the top components and think through how they could fit into the bigger picture of your site - either now or down the line.

I'm on record as stating that there are very few online project where you can't get close to what you need with Joomla. I know others who say the same about other Open Source CMSs and I won't argue.

Hand rolling your own solution is possible - but a solution pieced together with off the shelf components is generally massively cheaper - but may not have the same shelf life as hand rolling your own.

In the end you pays your money, you make your choice.  One thing I would suggest though - is not 'designing' your complete solution up front. Roll it out in stages. Begin with the bare minimum to make it workable - and add features over time.

Edited to add:

In terms of page load, etc - there is no reason a Joomla site can't be as fast as any other site on the web - as long as it has solid hosting. I may be breaking a community rule here but I'd offer our own site http://www.deanmarshall.co.uk/ as an example. We aim for the front page to load in under 1.5 seconds, with other pages in under 1 second.

Comment: Dean, thanks for the detailed answer to my question and for pointing out the extension options I have for various parts of the website. I see from your website that the page loads are indeed quite quick and that reassures me to some extent. I will certainly keep in mind your suggestions of rolling out the site in stages.

Answer (score -1):

You should try PyroCMS, way much easier than joomla and pretty good with the features for a portal.

Comment: The question is clearly 'choose between x and y' - I don't think suggestion 'z' helps.